# How to measure organics in liquid solution

Tags: organic-chemistry

We have a solution that has been put through a filter, it has gotten down to 20ppm. We want to know what the remaining organics are so we can try to filter those out. Is there any machine we can buy to determine this? What would this method of figuring out this problem called? Any direction to help me with this would be much help thank you.

Comment: The instruments are very expensive. You cannot buy it for your school project. For this type of work, a system called gas chromatograph with a mass detector (GC-MS) is used. See Wikipedia for more details.

Comment: "Filter them out"? What filter will remove dissolved organic chemicals? Activated carbon? How will it work?